# Location of #th iteration of a character or a word in a sql text field

Tags: sql-server

How can I get the location for the #th iteration of a character or a word in a sql server text field?

Comment: Did you try anything yourself? What?

Comment: Well I can use CHARINDEX, multiple time to get the same result, I was wondering if anybody knows an easier way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I even begin, these solutions deliver what's asked, but they should never be expected to perform well inside of SQL Server. Outside of Paul's suggestion to use SQLSharp, I think you will have much better results - if you care about performance - pulling these strings apart in your application logic, be it C#, PHP, what have you. That said...

**Single Character**

For a specific character, this isn't altogether too terrible, but I still suspect you will be better off doing this kind of thing in the application tier once you've pulled back the full value. First, create a numbers table, if you don't already have one - this one creates 50,000 rows, but you could easily extend the source set to a much higher number if need be:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Numbers(Number INT PRIMARY KEY);

;WITH [set] AS
(
  SELECT TOP (50000) Number = ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])
    FROM sys.objects AS s1
    CROSS JOIN sys.objects AS s2
    ORDER BY Number
)
INSERT dbo.Numbers WITH (TABLOCKX) (Number)
  SELECT Number FROM [set];
```

Now, you can create a function that just breaks the string into single characters, applying a number to represent the location within the string, and then a window function to indicate the appearance of that character:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FindCharacter
(
  @string VARCHAR(255),
  @character_to_find CHAR(1),
  @instance_of_character TINYINT
)
RETURNS INT
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN 
  (
    SELECT n FROM
    ( 
      SELECT n = number,
        s = SUBSTRING(@string, number, 1), 
        r = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
        ( 
          PARTITION BY SUBSTRING(@string, number, 1) 
          ORDER BY number
        )
        FROM dbo.Numbers_Set
        WHERE Number <= LEN(@string)
     ) AS x
     WHERE s = @character_to_find
       AND r = @instance_of_character
  );
END
GO
```

Sample usage:

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(i INT, s VARCHAR(255));

INSERT @x VALUES(1,'dhsjdhsdxshdsjdxkjsdxlsd'),
                (2,'sdsdxsdsdsxsxsdsd'),
                (3,'yyyyyyy');

DECLARE 
  @character_to_find VARCHAR(255) = 'x',
  @instance_of_character TINYINT = 3;

SELECT i, s, dbo.FindCharacter
  (s,@character_to_find,@instance_of_character)
  FROM @x;
```

Results:

```
i    s                          loc
---- -------------------------- ---
1    dhsjdhsdxshdsjdxkjsdxlsd   21
2    sdsdxsdsdsxsxsdsd          13
3    yyyyyyy                    NULL
```

**"Word" (sequence of characters)**

In this case the easiest approach I could think of was to use the same Numbers table as above, but from within an inline table-valued function. I am assuming that by "word" you simply mean "sequence of characters", and not literally a word separated by spaces (which would also be possible, but that's not what I solved for here).

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FindWord
(
  @string VARCHAR(255),
  @word_to_find VARCHAR(255),
  @instance_of_word TINYINT
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN ( SELECT loc FROM 
   (
     SELECT loc, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY loc)
     FROM 
     (
       SELECT loc = Number + CASE Number WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
         FROM dbo.Numbers WHERE Number <= CONVERT(INT, LEN(@string))
         AND SUBSTRING
         (@word_to_find + @string, Number, LEN(@word_to_find)) 
           = @word_to_find
     ) AS x
    ) AS y WHERE rn = @instance_of_word
   );
GO
```

Sample usage:

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(i INT, s VARCHAR(255));

INSERT @x VALUES(1,'dhsjdhsdxshdsjdxkjsdxlsd'),
                (2,'sdsdxsdsdsxsxsdsd'),
                (3,'yyyyyyy');

DECLARE 
  @word_to_find VARCHAR(255) = 'sd',
  @instance_of_word TINYINT = 3;

SELECT x.i, x.s, f.loc
  FROM @x AS x
  OUTER APPLY dbo.FindWord
    (x.s, @word_to_find, @instance_of_word) AS f;
```

Results:

```
i    s                          loc
---- -------------------------- ---
1    dhsjdhsdxshdsjdxkjsdxlsd   22
2    sdsdxsdsdsxsxsdsd          6
3    yyyyyyy                    NULL
```

**Word (separated by spaces)**

This is a slight variation of the above, but we need to split by spaces first, then find all the instances of the word we're after in that set.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FindWord2
(
   @string VARCHAR(255),
   @word_to_find VARCHAR(255),
   @instance_of_word TINYINT
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN
   ( SELECT loc = Number FROM
     (
       SELECT Number, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Number)
       FROM 
       (
         SELECT Number, 
           Item = SUBSTRING(@string, Number, 
           CHARINDEX(' ', @string + ' ', Number) - Number)
         FROM dbo.Numbers
         WHERE Number <= CONVERT(INT, LEN(@string))
           AND SUBSTRING(' ' + @string, Number, 1) = ' '
       ) AS x WHERE Item = @word_to_find
     ) AS y WHERE rn = @instance_of_word
   );
GO
```

Sample usage:

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(i INT, s VARCHAR(255));

INSERT @x VALUES(1,'hot axe hot goo shot fud hot'),
                (2,'hot bling foo hot x hot what'),
                (3,'yyyyyyy');

DECLARE 
  @word_to_find VARCHAR(255) = 'hot',
  @instance_of_word TINYINT = 3;

SELECT x.i, x.s, f.loc
  FROM @x AS x
  OUTER APPLY dbo.FindWord2
    (x.s, @word_to_find, @instance_of_word) AS f;
```

Results:

```
i    s                            loc
---- ---------------------------- ----
1    hot axe hot goo shot fud hot 26 
2    hot bling foo hot x hot what 21
3    yyyyyyy                      NULL
```

**Once again**

This is not going to break any performance records; if you can seek more efficient ways to do this outside of the constructs of plain T-SQL, I highly advise that you do so.

Answer (score 2):

There's no specific support for this in Transact-SQL.

You could write your own function using `CHARINDEX`.

Alternatively, you could use a library that someone else has already written, for example [the SQLsharp SQLCLR extension library](http://www.sqlsharp.com). Among the over 240 functions and procedures is `SQL#.String_NthIndexOf`:

```
-- Result: 13
SELECT SQL#.String_NthIndexOf
(
    N'abc abc abc abc abc',  -- Input string
    N'abc',                  -- Search for this
    1,                       -- Starting at position
    4,                       -- Nth occurrence
    1,                       -- Case sensitive
    0                        -- Don't count overlaps
);
```

I have no association with this (mostly free) product, I am just a fan.